# Use neighborhood signs to express e, pi, phi

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, pi

Is the above description true or false?

$$e=\left(1+\pi-(5^{±})\arccos\left(\fracφ2\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{π-(5^{±})\arccos\left(\fracφ2\right)}}$$

Comment: Yes. How are you getting all these weird identities?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $5^{\pm1}$ or maybe $5\pm\arccos(…)$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I updated (5±) and Read "Mathematics" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#:~:text=The%20plus%20and%20minus%20signs,subtraction%2C%20resulting%20in%20a%20difference.

Comment: What are "neighborhood signs"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm Vietnamese and I study Math, so the concept of "lân cận" is called neighborhood

Answer (score 5):

The formula is indeed true, if interpreted appropriately, but you have given it in an entirely unintuitive way. The meaning of the expression $5^{\pm}$ is wholly non-obvious and it could easily have been interpreted as addition, $5{\pm}\ldots$, or exponentiation, $5^{\pm1}$, despite that for the equation to be true, it must mean **approaching** the number, ($5{\pm}\varepsilon$), where $\varepsilon$ is a small, positive real. In future, please take care to **explain your notation** in the body of your text, or use notation that is more obvious in its context.

With this in mind, the RHS expression becomes $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\pi-\left(5+x\right)\arccos\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{\pi-\left(5+x\right)\arccos\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)}}$$

The equation is true because $5\arccos\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)=\pi$, so it is directly equivalent to the well-known limit $\lim_{u\to0} \left(1+u\right)^{\frac{1}{u}}$, where $u=-\frac{\pi}{5}x$ and if $x\to0$, then $u\to0$. That is to say, the $\pi$ and $\arccos\ldots$ terms effectively cancel each other out and amount to a scaling of $x$ that is inconsequential to the limit.